# How to implement Sidebar with sub sidebar using react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom, sidebar, react-sidebar

I'm trying to make a sidebar with a sub sidebar where each item in the main sidebar has a few sub-items that need to be listed in the sub sidebar.
just as shown below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

so its quite complex but you will understand and get all of the code

first, let's create the style

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;

    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    height: 100vh;
}

body > #root {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}


body > #root > #sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;

    background: #EBE9EB;
    border-right: solid 1px black;
}

body > #root > #sub-sidebar {
    float: left;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;

    background: #EBE9EB;
}

body > #root > #content {
    float: left;
    width: 60%;
    height: 100%;

    background: white;
}
```

and inside the app component put

```
import * as React from "react";
import "./style.css";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    sidebar: 0, // index of the sidebar
    sub_sidebar: 0, // index of the sub sidebar
  }

  // method to rendering the content
  renderingTheContent = () => {
    // switching the content with index of sidebar and the sub-sidebar
    switch (this.state.sidebar) {
      case 0:
        switch (this.state.sub_sidebar) {
          case 0:
            return <span>overview</span>;
          case 1:
            return <span>hello</span>;
        }
      case 1:
        switch (this.state.sub_sidebar) {
          case 0:
            return <span>hola</span>;
          case 1:
            return <span>shop</span>;
        }
      case 2:
        switch (this.state.sub_sidebar) {
          case 0:
            return <span>black</span>;
          case 1:
            return <span>red</span>;
        }
    }
  }

  // method to rendering the sub sidebar
  renderingTheSubSideBar = () => {
    // switching the sub-sidebar with index of sidebar
    switch (this.state.sidebar) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <ul>
            <li onClick={() => this.setSubSideBar(0)}>overview</li>
            <li onClick={() => this.setSubSideBar(1)}>hello</li>
          </ul>
        );
      case 1:
        return (
          <ul>
            <li onClick={() => this.setSubSideBar(0)}>hola</li>
            <li onClick={() => this.setSubSideBar(1)}>shop</li>
          </ul>
        );
      case 2:
        return (
          <ul>
            <li onClick={() => this.setSubSideBar(0)}>black</li>
            <li onClick={() => this.setSubSideBar(1)}>red</li>
          </ul>
        );
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <React.Fragment>
        {/*first side bar*/}
        <div id={"sidebar"}>
          <ul>
            <li onClick={() => this.setSideBar(0)}>Dashboard</li>
            <li onClick={() => this.setSideBar(1)}>hello</li>
            <li onClick={() => this.setSideBar(2)}>welcome</li>
          </ul>
        </div>

        {/*the sub side bar*/}
        <div id={"sub-sidebar"}>
          {this.renderingTheSubSideBar()}
        </div>

        {/*the content*/}
        <div id={"content"}>
          {this.renderingTheContent()}
        </div>
      </React.Fragment>
    );
  };

  // set the new index of the sidebar
  setSideBar = (newSidebar) => {
    this.setState({sidebar: newSidebar});
  }

  // set the new index of the sub sidebar
  setSubSideBar = (newSubSidebar) => {
    this.setState({sub_sidebar: newSubSidebar});
  }
}
```